# d3.js-v4 stacked bars chart

Tags: d3.js

I have a problem with creating stacked bar chart.

I made the following example and it's fine
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

But now I have other data format: *(this is short example of my data)*

```
var data = [
  {
    "PERIOD": 2014001,
    "SUBMITTER": "oanikit2",
    "distr_count": 16
  },
  {
    "PERIOD": 2014001,
    "SUBMITTER": "nvlodavs",
    "distr_count": 21
  },
  {
    "PERIOD": 2014001,
    "SUBMITTER": "manufrie",
    "distr_count": 39
  },
  {
    "PERIOD": 2014001,
    "SUBMITTER": "mtalyshi",
    "distr_count": 14
  }
]
```

using nested I converted it into: *(short data example below)*

```
 var nested = d3.nest().key(function (d){return d.SUBMITTER}).entries(data);
    d3.select("body").append("pre").text(JSON.stringify(nested,null,2)); //just to render data on page 

[
  {
    "key": "oanikit2",
    "values": [
      {
        "PERIOD": 2014001,
        "SUBMITTER": "oanikit2",
        "distr_count": 16
      },
      {
        "PERIOD": 2014002,
        "SUBMITTER": "oanikit2",
        "distr_count": 18
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "nvlodavs",
    "values": [
      {
        "PERIOD": 2014001,
        "SUBMITTER": "nvlodavs",
        "distr_count": 21
      },
      {
        "PERIOD": 2014002,
        "SUBMITTER": "nvlodavs",
        "distr_count": 24
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

but have no idea how to move further. How to get y0 values?
need series on PERIOD and stacked SUBMITTER with distr_count as values.

Tried to follow other examples of stacked bars,
but all of them about v3. I'm new in D3 so I decided to start with v4 from the beginning. But there is too little examples online.

Maybe you have more examples (links) how to use D3 v4 (stacked bars)?

p.s. also  posted to google questions (can't give a link because of my reputation)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. It seems like the new d3.stack v4 expects your data to be:

```
date | apples| oranges| feijoas
-----|-------|--------|-------
2015 | 10    | 20     | 30
2016 | 5     | 10     | 15
```

So it seems like it won't work with the output of nest

Comment: The data format is fine if you're working with a csv file, but i'm working with java objects and tailored my data to the exact format he shows here, the `layers` object. https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Stack-Layout.md. It was convenient because the stacked data was available as `"values"`, but you could also have other properties such as `"name"`, `"id"` or w/e, and then during selections you could access those properties. I'm not sure how to fit my existing data format to the one that version 4 expects...